# Knights of the Old Republic Canon

Tags: star-wars, canon

Are the lore associated with Knights of the Old Republic (and soon to be released Old Republic) video game considered as Star Wars canon?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1806/what-is-the-singular-source-of-star-wars-canonization/1809#1809), I believe that SW: KOTOR and the sequel are considered C-level canon.  It is canon unless it contradicts something that is in a novel or in G-level canon.

In any SW video game with multiple endings to quests, I believe that the canon resolution is the 'best' one - the one that offers the most 'light side' points.  In canon, I believe that all side quests are considered to be taken.

It's also worth pointing out that video games are typically considered 'less canon' than the EU novels - G-level trumps novels, novels trump video games.  Comics most likely fall in with novels, except when they're tied to a game - then the comic trumps gameplay, but an EU novel still trumps it.

Comment: G-level means the movies right?

Comment: @Jonn: Movies, novelizations thereof, and Lucas interviews.

Comment: @Jef: What are you referring to? `:)`

Comment: adding to this answer: some "more canonical" works like novels and whatnot seemly mention Kotor character (like Darth Nihilus) and seemly Lucas had a good amount of input in making Kotor series (for example in Kotor2 you can turn your followers in Jedi, except the wookie one, because Lucas explicitly forbid that).