# Did Palpatine foresee that Anakin would kill him?

Tags: star-wars, darth-sidious

I read it somewhere in the 90s that Palpatine/Sidious had a vision in which he foresaw that Anakin would kill him and the reason why he tried to turn him to the Dark Side is to make sure it doesn't come true. I think it was in one of the booklets that were released with the X-Wing and TIE fighter games.

Comment: The rule of two that Sith follow dictates that eventually each apprentice kills their master, but its unlikely Sidious ever intended for that to happen.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This would be a much better answer if you could provide a reference to the game book you're referring to.

Comment: @DJSpicyDeluxe *Each* apprentice, or eventually *one* apprentice? The difference matters, because the latter would mean it wasn't necessarily Anakin that would kill Palpatine.

Comment: @AndresF. Each, assuming the apprentice didn't die somehow first

Comment: @DJSpicyDeluxe If this booklet was from the 1990's, then that might have been before George Lucas (or anybody else) invented the Rule of Two.

Comment: He was possibly aware of the prophecy about bringing balance to the Force, and that's why he feared Anakin/Vader? Particularly after they wiped out the Jedi together, creating a huge imbalance. I imagine that's why he was so keen to bring Luke over, so that Vader could be replaced (although it's surprising he didn't foresee that it would likely be the attempt to bring Luke over that caused Vader to turn).

Comment: ....did Anakin actually kill Palpatine?  ;)

Comment: Anakin/Darth killed the ORIGINAL Palpatine. The ROS Palpatine was one of his clones. I think the Sith Eternal were all clones of him, right?

Comment: @DavidW : I hope I answered your question in the other post. I don’t know if this site can do private messages. Here is the link where I answered:   

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71843/how-did-people-know-emperor-palpatines-name-before-the-release-of-prequel-trilo/226595#226595