# What is the name of the vehicle used by the Jawas?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

In the Star Wars movie "A New Hope", there were some small creatures called Jawas in the planet Tatooine. They were using a big vehicle to put captured droids & other stuff. What is this vehicle's name, and is it bullet-proof?

Comment: English tip: you don't need to start a word with a capital letter unless it's either at the start of a sentence or it's the name of a person or place or part of the title of e.g. a movie or book.

Comment: @Randal'Thor, Thank you so much for your Tip.. i'm really a very Bad person in English..

Comment: I'd think he is from a german speaking country, like myself, we do this because it's part of our written language and we basically have years of learning about what to write in caps and what not and then we translate that to written english as well because it seems so natural, bad habit, you know ;)

Comment: @DennisChristian - Or maybe Qatar. ;)

Comment: No People.. i'm a Sri lankan who stays in Qatar..

Comment: haha, ok, well why do you think you make the caps action? maybe this is a question for english learning SE ;D

Comment: @DennisChristian, Everyday i'm Learning something from this Site.. :-)

Comment: Given that even storm troopers were able to shoot it, its defensive capabilities are *seriously* in question.

Comment: @DennisChristian You're supposed to write the names of languages with capitals...

Comment: I like the vibe of scifi SE so much more than StackOverflow these days. This question totally would have been closed by a user with gold in the "star-wars" tag and some equivalent of a "RTF(ine)M noob" comment. Stay cool, SF&F :)

Comment: it would be easier if we would just randomly enable/disable caps while writing. And punctuation marks are also overrated. ;P

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's called a [Sandcrawler](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sandcrawler).

From the starwars.wikia article:

> Sandcrawlers were huge mobile fortresses which could be seen on the deserts of Tatooine, used by the Jawas as their transport and shelter. They were equipped with a magnetic suction tube for sucking droids and scrap into the cargo hold. They were equipped with cargo holds, scrap processing facilities and quarters for crew and passengers.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Delel.jpg) They were large enough to fit an entire Jawa clan.

[image: Sandcrawler]

Comment: I would also think it's "bulletproof", certainly from the projectile weapons the sand people use.

Comment: @iMerchant The stormtroopers managed to destroy one in _A New Hope_, so not blaster-proof.  Apparently it was big enough that even stormtroopers couldn't miss! :D

Comment: @JaneS "only imperial stormtroopers are so precise" ;p

Comment: @JaneS But was it because of the lack of blaster proofing, or because of an internal sneak attack. I could easily see that "Let me inspect your vehicle as the galactic military...POW" to be a pretty plausible situation.

Comment: From the actual script for SW:ANH - EXT. TATOOINE - ROCK CANYON - SANDCRAWLER - SUNSET

               The eight Jawas carry Artoo out of the canyon to a huge tank-
               like vehicle the size of a four-story house. They weld a 
               small disk on the side of Artoo and then put him under a 
               large tube on the side of the vehicle and the little robot 
               is sucked into the giant machine.

Comment: @thunderforge - Your edit adds brand new information rather than improving the existing answer. I've rolled it back to its earlier format. You might want to consider adding this information as a brand new answer

Comment: @Valorum I had thought that adding new supporting information was improving the answer. I've moved it to a new answer, although now there are two competing answers rather than just one good answer with all the information :-/

Comment: @PTwr *Precision* allows them to hit the same thing over and over. *Accuracy* allows them to hit the thing they want to hit. Storm troopers seem be very precise yet horribly inaccurate; they consistently hit the air around their targets.

Comment: @Thunderforge - Having generated *new information*, you deserve to benefit from it. It's down to the OP (and the community) to decide which answer they find most useful. What you've done is what I tend to describe as "good vandalism".

Comment: @Anoplexian In the movie, Obi-wan points out the blaster damage on the burned out shell.  The implication was strongly that it had been destroyed by blaster fire ("No, it was Imperial troops.  Sandpeople ride single file to hide their numbers.")

Comment: @JaneS Huh. I don't remember the blaster marks (although IIRC he does mention only storm troopers are so precise. I always thought it was more like they disabled it and then took care of it, but I digress), but I did remember the single file part.

Answer (score 7):

Although it is not named on screen, the vehicle is explicitly called a "Sandcrawler" multiple times in the script of *A New Hope*:

```
EXT. TATOOINE - ROCK CANYON - SANDCRAWLER - SUNSET

The eight Jawas carry Artoo out of the canyon to a huge tank-
like vehicle the size of a four-story house. They weld a 
small disk on the side of Artoo and then put him under a 
large tube on the side of the vehicle and the little robot 
is sucked into the giant machine.

[...]

INT. SANDCRAWLER - HOLD AREA

It is dim inside the hold area of the Sandcrawler. Artoo 
switches on a small floodlight on his forehead and stumbles 
around the scrap heap.
```

*Star Wars* has a history of giving names to things in scripts, but not saying them on screen. For instance, the glowing thing held up in the parade at the end of *The Phantom Menace* is named the "Globe of Peace" in the script, but not identidied on screen. Also, some names appear only in the script and credits, such as the name "Ewoks" only appears in the script and credits for *Return of the Jedi*, but are not said on screen.

Comment: The name "ewoks" **is** [mentioned on-screen](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/51331/20774).

Comment: +1 for canon source (though I did +1 the other answer too).

Comment: @Valorum I meant in dialog, but you're right, it is in the credits. Edited my response.

Comment: I was sure that 'Sandcrawler' was mentioned in the film? By Luke, IIRC.