# Is the content from the X-wing miniatures game canon?

Tags: star-wars, canon

I'm a big fan of the [X-Wing miniatures game by Fantasy Flight Games](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/products/x-wing/). The game first came out before Disney changed the *Star Wars* canon to include only content created after April 25, 2014 and all the movies/TV shows.

The game references a lot of *Legends* material, has created some of its own new material, and has re-worked some other non-canon material.

Since there have been releases post-April 2014, is the game considered canon? Are only the newer releases canon? Or is it all *Legends*?

Comment: It's almost certainly considered Legends, especially since it's an existing title with its own continuity.

Comment: [It's *Legends* all the way down](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/910/how-is-canonicity-of-derivative-works-determined-for-star-wars/80098#80098)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### It appears to be Legends canon (not "Disney" canon)

Although the X-Wing miniatures game has had releases since the new canon rules took effect, such new content is still considered to be in Legends continuity.

An excellent example of this is the [Imperial Raider expansion pack](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/X-Wing:_Imperial_Raider_Expansion_Pack) set to be released in 2015. The [press release announcing the expansion pack](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/news/2014/12/19/here-comes-the-imperial-raider/) describes how the Raider-class ship was created by Fantasy Flight Games for the miniatures game as a counterpart to the Tantive IV. The ship was designed in partnership with Lucasfilm, who of course decide what is part of the current continuity and was is part of Legends.

There are several signs that show that this ship is in Legends continuity, including references to locations and characters that are in Legends continuity (such as Kuat shipyards), and the BBY designation for the year, which is no longer used. [The Wookieepedia article for the ship itself](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Raider-class_corvette) lists the Raider-class ship as being firmly in Legends continuity. As a reminder, this is despite being created in partnership with Lucasfilm and despite being released over a year after the new canon rules.

Other products in the line have similar indications that they are in the Legends continuity. This is corroborated by the fact that [lists of works that are in the new canon](http://www.swbooks.co.uk/saga/) do not list X-Wing, or Fantasy Flight's other miniatures game, [Star Wars: Armada](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Armada).

While Fantasy Flight Games has never released an official statement about the canonicity of the game, all signs point to it as not being part of the current continuity.

Comment: Although - the Raider is now canon because it made an appearance as the primary craft of Inferno Squad in both the book "Battlefront II: Inferno Squad" and the canon single-player storyline in Star Wars Battlefront: II

Comment: @NKCampbell Interesting, I wasn’t aware of that. Well, at the time it was introduced, it was definitely “new” Legends, despite most new stuff at the time being Disney canon.

Comment: entirely agree - I play FFG stuff myself and was quite excited to see the Raider make a canon appearance

Answer (score 0):

No, It is not canon as the franchise started before the 2014 reboot.

Thanks Jason Baker for linking [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/910/how-is-canonicity-of-derivative-works-determined-for-star-wars/80098#80098) question.

It is also not listed on this [comprehensive list](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline_of_canon_media) from *Wookieepedia*

Comment: I don't think that the timeline of canon sources on Wookieepedia would definitively answer this question, since the game doesn't tell a "story" at a particular time and place.