# What does the inclusion of various KOTOR planets in G and C level canon mean for its canonicity?

Tags: star-wars, canon

This is the galaxy map found in The Force Awakens: Visual Dictionary,

[image: TFA Visual Dictionary galaxy map]

sorry for the bad quality picture.

You can see Rakata Prime included among most the canon planets and they even chose to include Rakata Prime over Kamino and Mustafar.

As some of you know already, Rakata prime is a planet from KOTOR that had extreme significance. I realize that, [based on this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1806/what-is-the-singular-source-of-star-wars-canonization/1809#1809), KOTOR was somewhere between C and S canon.

In addition:

- Taris was mentioned in Star Wars: Aftermath

  > They stand in a tenement on Taris...
- Malachor is mentioned as Kylo Ren's lightsaber is said to be patterned on a Sith lord called "The scourge of Malachor".
- Darth Bane is featured in an episode of Star Wars: The Clone Wars (TV series) (can't remember which season/episode)

So **what do these fairly direct references mean for the level of canonicity of Knight of The Old Republic?**

Note I am not asking for plot speculation (as delicious as it may be) based on these developments, also I do not believe this is a duplicate of the question I linked as this question is based on modern developments.

Comment: To quote Lucasfilm's [Pablo Hidalgo](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/681186814544105472); "*If canon story references X, which appeared in story Y, it does not follow that Y is also canon. Just X. Discuss. Somewhere else.*"

Answer (score 1):

According to [a panel at Celebration Anaheim last year](http://www.starwars.com/news/swca-one-big-story-star-wars-canon-panel-liveblog), *Knights of the Old Republic* is officially non-canon:

> Are The Old Republic expansions canon?
>
> No — BioWare “has created their own universe that is so fantastic,” we’re not going to change it, says Hidalgo.

Although this event occurred before all of the releases quoted in the question (except for the *Clone Wars* episode), it would seem to imply that merely referencing something introduced in a non-canon work does not make the entire work canon.

Later remarks by Leland Chee at that panel suggest that the Old Republic time period may be visited in canon:

> When are you going to explore the Old Republic part of the timeline?
>
> “It’s definitely not off the table.” — Chee

So we may find out more in the future.

Comment: Well what does the inclusion of a planet like Rakata Prime mean then? The events of KOTOR occured? or just that a planet called Rakata prime exists with none of the lore attached to kotor?

Comment: @Hatandboots The second one. That's not to say they won't bring elements from KOTOR into canon; Hidalgo says a little later in that panel that popular Legends characters will be introduced to the canon, which may include Revan (for example), but until they actually visit or reference that time period, it's all legends

Comment: I find this very confusing. Would the same apply to a character? If a canon novel talked about Revan, would his kotor history be included in this version of him, or would this Revan be a blank slate with only whatever history they provide?

Comment: @Hatandboots Again, the second one. If it helps, pretend you've never heard of KOTOR; it's *all* brand-new, and whatever they reveal in canon materials is what is canon. Anything not in canon materials is not canon

Comment: OK I understand now. Thanks for making sense of it for me. I am however very disappointed that this is the case.